# how can i call template function not using explicit type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

When I wrote C++ code like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    std::shared_ptr<T> left;
    std::shared_ptr<T> right;

    Node(const T& data)
        :data(data)
    {}
};

template <typename T>
void PreorderTraverse(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>& root, 
                      std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>&)> callback = nullptr)
{
    callback(root);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto root = make_shared<Node<int>>(5);
    // Why must write template type explicitly?
    //PreorderTraverse(root, [](shared_ptr<Node<int>>& node)->void { cout << node->data << endl; });

    PreorderTraverse<int>(root, [](shared_ptr<Node<int>>& node)->void { cout << node->data << endl; });

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

I can't call PreorderTraverse like this perform

> PreorderTraverse(root, [](shared_ptr<Node>& node)->void { cout << node->data << endl; });

maybe compiler can't infer instance type, then how should I modify this code for compiler to be able to infer for call 'PreorderTraverse' like comment above?

Comment: sorry, I have some typo. perform -> form. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the template is too complicated for the compiler to deduce. More specifically, the second argument is a closure (the anonymous type created by a lambda expression), not a `std::function` - it's compatible with a `std::function` that takes the first `shared_ptr` as an argument, but that's too complicated a deduction chain for the compiler to work out according to the standard rules.

One solution would be to make the second argument a separate type:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void PreorderTraverse(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>& root, F callback) {
    callback(root);
}
```

Comment: "too complicated for the compiler to deduce" that is never a thing.

Comment: There are actual rules in the standard that dictates what's allowed and how things work. If you don't know them or don't want to explain them in your answer, that's fine... but don't make up some random "it's too complicated..." reason.

Answer (score 3):

`PreorderTraverse` is taking `std::function`, and you're passing a lambda. Unfortunately implicit conversion (from lambda to `std::function`) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), which fails deducing `T` on the 2nd function parameter `callback`.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

You can use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (since C++20) to exclude `callback` from deduction.

```
template <typename T>
void PreorderTraverse(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>& root,                                    
                      std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Node<std::type_identity_t<T>>>&)> callback = nullptr)
//                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^
{
    callback(root);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZRnOdLAfMB1wUe12)

Or Add another template parameter and stop using `std::function`. E.g.

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void PreorderTraverse(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>& root, 
                      F callback)
{
    callback(root);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ic1ccqGqV7tYaelw)

Comment: Thank you! I learnd many things from your comments.